# TSQL - Insert values in table based on lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lookup

I have a master table in sql server 2012 that consists of two types.

These are the critical columns I have in my master table:

```
TYPE    CATEGORYGROUP   CREDITORNAME    DEBITORNAME
```

One of those two types (Type B) doesn't have a CategoryGroup assigned to it (so it's always null).

Type A always has a CategoryGroup and Debitor.

Type B always has a Creditor but no CategoryGroup.

For creditor and debitor I have two extra tables that also hold the CategoryGroup but for my task I only need the table for creditors since I already have the right value for type A (debitors).

So my goal is to look-up the CategoryGroup in the creditor table based on the creditor name and ideally put those CategoryGroup values in my master table.
With "put" I'm not sure if a view should be generated or actually put the data in the table which contains about 1.5 million records and keeps on growing.

There's also a "cluster table" that uses the CategoryGroup as a key field. But this isn't part of my problem here.

Please have a look at my sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c653b/1)

Hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply do a join to find the correct value, and update MainData with that value;

You can either use a common table expression...

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT a.*, b.categorygroup cg
  FROM MainData a
  JOIN CreditorList b
    ON a.creditorname = b.creditorname
)
UPDATE cte SET categorygroup=cg;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88024/1).

...or an UPDATE/JOIN;

```
UPDATE m
SET m.categorygroup = c.categorygroup
FROM maindata m
JOIN creditorlist c
  ON m.creditorname = c.creditorname;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41507/2).

...and always remember to test before running potentially destructive SQL from random people on the Internet on your production data.

EDIT: To just see the date in the same format without doing the update, you can use;

```
SELECT 
  a.type, COALESCE(a.categorygroup, b.categorygroup) categorygroup,
  a.creditorname, a.debitorname
FROM MainData a
LEFT JOIN CreditorList b
  ON a.creditorname = b.creditorname
```

[Yet another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88024/9).

Comment: thank you for the samples! Instead of an update is there a way to leave the main data table untouched and recreate the join process via a view every time the data is requested? This view would only be executed once a day.

Comment: @TonyClifton Added a select that gives the same result without altering your data.

Comment: thank you very much Joachim - the COALESCE function did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do:

```
update maindata
set categorygroup = (
    select top 1 categorygroup 
    from creditorlist 
    where creditorname = maindata.creditorname)
where creditorname is not null
and categorygroup is null
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
update m
set m.CategoryGroup = cl.CategoryGroup
-- select m.creditorName, 
-- m.CategoryGroup as Dest, 
-- cl.CategoryGroup as Src
from maindata as m
left join creditorlist as cl
on m.creditorName = cl.creditorName
where m.creditorName is not null
```

Before you update, you can check the results of the query by uncommenting the update statement and removing the updates.